# how draw line using Intercept and slope in php

Tags: php, draw, jpeg

I want to draw a line use of php and my data is like this :

> y=m*x+c

is there any library for this goal?!

Answer (score 0):

Try [PHPLot](http://www.phplot.com/). You can very easily [plot functions](http://www.phplot.com/phplotdocs/ex-lines2.html) with it.